# How to kill a process on a port on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, port, kill

I am trying to kill a process in the command line for a specific port in ubuntu.

If I run this command I get the port:

```
sudo lsof -t -i:9001
```

so...now I want to run:

```
sudo kill 'sudo lsof -t -i:9001'
```

I get this error message:

```
ERROR: garbage process ID "lsof -t -i:9001".
Usage:
  kill pid ...              Send SIGTERM to every process listed.
  kill signal pid ...       Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -s signal pid ...    Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -l                   List all signal names.
  kill -L                   List all signal names in a nice table.
  kill -l signal            Convert between signal numbers and names.
```

I tried `sudo kill 'lsof -t -i:9001'` as well

Comment: FYI, Ubuntu questions have better chance of being answered on the Ubuntu part of the StackExchange (StackOverflow) network: http://askubuntu.com

Comment: Honestly, you should use fuser, as it is very simple, but whatever.

Comment: just for myself `sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)`

Answer (score 1795, accepted):

You want to use backtick, not regular tick:

```sh
sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:9001`
```

If that doesn't work, you could also use `$()` for command interpolation:

```sh
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:9001)
```

Comment: @FrancescoGramano: you don't want to use -9 unless you have to.

Comment: when `sudo kill` can't kill the process, @putra.koreng 's method works well

Comment: if above is not working then try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50515868/9339242

Comment: Is this OS independent or linux specific? If Linux specific then, even this command works
`os.system("fuser -k 8080/tcp");`

Comment: This closes my browser entirely https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621849/4579897 works

Comment: `sudo fuser 9001/tcp -k` in case the above command does not work for you.

Comment: You may want to run the inner part (i.e. `sudo lsof -t -i:9001`) to check to see what processes are returned. For me, it returned PIDs for both the server _and_ clients, which is probably what happened to @AdamWinnipass.

Comment: sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:8000`

Comment: Does not work anymore. Only comes up with a help command for both commands

Comment: @EpicSpeedy 
It shows you the help command when it doesn't find the process that you want to kill. That means you probably chose a wrong port or the process stop already

Comment: It is highly recommended *not* to use `kill -9` unless you have to.  `kill -9` will just rip the process out of the process table and clean up what the OS knowns about (e.g. memory).  Instead use `kill -HUP`, if that doesn't work then `kill -INT`, then if necessary `kill -9`.  The first two will give the process a chance to clean up its own matters before exiting.

Comment: Also works on mac much better than others I've tried

Comment: just for myself `sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)`

Answer (score 424):

you can use

```
fuser -n tcp -k 9001
```

[see more details in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_%28Unix%29)

Comment: If not root: sudo fuser -n tcp -k 9001

Answer (score 161):

FOR UBUNTU
1- Find what application/process is using the pro, type:

```
sudo netstat -lpn |grep :8080
```

and press Enter.

You will get an output similar to this one

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      6782/java
```

2- I have got the process Id, which is 6782, now this is the process that is using port 8080.

3- Kill the process, type: kill -p 6782

```
kill -9 6782
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. even I tried to kill process with `sudo` on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @MuhammadTariq Try using kill -9 {PID}

Comment: Step 3: reply: kill -p 6782 by: kill -9 6782 -> it work for me

Comment: I used sudo and it worked

Comment: @MuhammadTariq then you don't have running process on that port.

Comment: It worked for me everytime. Thanks @Mohit Singh

Answer (score 124):

The best way to kill a port in the Ubuntu terminal is with the `fuser` command; e.g.:

```
fuser -k 9001/tcp
```

This sends `SIGKILL` by default.

Comment: this didn't work for me on local host 3000

Answer (score 39):

To kill a **process** running on Port number `9001`

```
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:9001)


lsof   - list of files(Also used for to list related processes)

-t     - show only process ID

-i     - show only internet connections related process

:9001  - show only processes in this port number

kill   - command to kill the process

-9     - forcefully

sudo   - command to ask admin privilege(user id and password).
```

for more you can visit my [blog](http://codinginterviewquestionsans.blogspot.in/2018/03/how-to-kill-process-on-port-on.html)

Answer (score 37):

There are some process which does not shown using normal netstat command, so you have to check it using `sudo`.

Do `sudo netstat -lpn |grep :8080`. Process running by system does not show PID, to get PID of this process you will have to run it using `sudo`

And then killl the process using port `8080`. You may have to use `sudo` here as well. So to kill this process use `sudo kill -9 PID`

Answer (score 24):

Use [killport](https://github.com/abdennour/miscs.sh/blob/master/killport) command :

```
sh killport 9001
```

To Download shell ,you can use `wget` :

```
wget https://cdn.rawgit.com/abdennour/miscs.sh/e0aac343/killport
```

Comment: if it is not work , that it means the target port is already closed

Answer (score 20):

```
killport <port>
```

Add this code in your CLI and use this alias.

```bash
killport () {
  PID=$(sudo lsof -t -i:$1)
  sudo kill -9 ${PID}
}
```

Comment: What "below bash code"?

Comment: added screenshot of the function which I added in ".bashrc"

Comment: Best answer I've seen in a while!

Answer (score 17):

**Lets consider If you want to kill a port 3000.**

**Step 1**: Run this command, which will give u its PID.

```
sudo lsof -t -i:3000
```

*This returned me PID as 291141*

**Step 2**: Run this command to kill the port using PID.

```
sudo kill -9 291141
```

**Boom!!! Port killed**

Answer (score 15):

To kill the process based on port first we have to find out the relevant pid for given port and kill using that pid,

In my case i wanted to get the pid(process id) of 3000 port:

```
netstat -ltnp | grep -w '3000'
```

then find pid which is listening to tcp

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      29972/node
```

you will get pid **29972**

To kill this pid use below command

```
kill -9 29972
```

pseudo code for kill process based on port

```
 netstat -ltnp | grep -w 'PORT'
```

and

```
kill -9 PID
```

Answer (score 14):

`sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:9001)` worked for me or
you can use

```
sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:9001`
```

replace 9001 with port number you want.

Answer (score 12):

Use this:

```
sudo kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:9001)
```

Comment: this worked for me on ubuntu 20.04, This is best because it merge 2 steps into one command.

Answer (score 11):

Just enter the following command in the terminal

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:3000)
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use following command in terminal
`fuser -k 3000/tcp`

Answer (score 5):

Kill PORT:

`sudo` is important to show process id.

```
$ sudo netstat -antlp | grep 45136
tcp      0      0 0.0.0.0:45136         0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN           **-** 

$ kill -9 45136
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the command

```
 netstat -plten |grep java
```

used grep java as tomcat uses java as their processes.

It will show the list of processes with port number and process id

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      
1000       30070621    16085/java
```

the number before /java is a process id. Now use kill command to kill the process

```
kill -9 16085
```

-9 implies the process will be killed forcefully.

Answer (score 5):

If I was you,I would use

```
fuser -k -n tcp PORT
kill -9 PID
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add an alias to your `.bashrc` / `.zshrc`:

1. Open new terminal
2. nano .bashrc
3. scroll down and add an alias:
   `alias kp='kill_process_by_port() { sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:"$1"); }; kill_process_by_port "$@"'`
4. ctrl + x +y
5. source .bashrc
6. kp 9000

Comment: lsof: unacceptable port specification in: -i :
lsof 4.93.2
 latest revision: https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof
 latest FAQ: https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof/blob/master/00FAQ
 latest (non-formatted) man page: https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof/blob/master/Lsof.8
 usage: [-?abhKlnNoOPRtUvVX] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-E] [+|-e s] [+|-f[gG]]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+m [m]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
 [+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.
kill: (8000): No such process

Comment: Fixed: `alias kp='kill_process_by_port() { sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:"$1"); }; kill_process_by_port "$@"'`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
lsof -i :port

or 

sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8000)

or

kill -9 <pid>

or 

sh killport 8000
```

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 17 and `kill -9 <pid>` worked great for me!

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:9001`
```

you don't have to add the `-9`signal option

Answer (score 3):

It gives me an error `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`. using the following method solved my error in Ubuntu.(`VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"`)

```
$ sudo netstat -lpn |grep :5000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25959/uwsgi   

$ fuser -k -n tcp 5000
5000/tcp:            25959
```

Hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` can be a very useful command.

You can pipe commands like this

```
lsof -t -i :9001 | xargs sudo kill
```

What it does:
it takes the output from the first command, in this case the process running on port, and will pass it to `sudo kill`.

Answer (score 2):

When using newer versions of Ubuntu you won't have `netcat` anymore, instead you use `ss`

```
ss -lptpn | grep 9001   
sudo kill <replace-with-process-id>
```

Answer (score 2):

- get PID of process running on port 3000:

  `lsof -i tcp:3000`
- kill th process

  `kill -9 process_id`

Example:
`lsof -i tcp:3000`

(PID in output = 5805)
`kill -9 5805`

> use `sudo` if required

Answer (score 2):

On my ubuntu-22.04 machine, this worked to kill port 8000

`fuser -k 8000/tcp`

Answer (score 1):

Its two steps process:

1. Know process id on port no. 8080 (can be any)
2. Kill process of that id 8689 (can be different)

   ```
   fuser -n tcp 8080

   #o/p 8080/tcp    8689

   kill -9 8689
   ```

Answer (score 1):

you can work this using node

```
npm install freethenport -g
```

then

```
node freethenport 9001
```

Answer (score 1):

Displays active TCP connections, ports on which the computer is listening.

```
netstat -tupln
```

It will list you all the connection along pid. Find and copy the pid and run the following command. Make sure you replace the  with actual id in the following command.

```
kill -9 <copied pid>
```

> -9 use to forcefully kill the connection.

Answer (score 1):

**sudo netstat -lpn |grep :8080**

than get the PID of this process

**kill -9**

Answer (score 1):

You can also use xargs. Just run the following,

sudo lsof -t -i:443 | xargs sudo kill -9

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).