# nodemon giving this error code: 'EADDRINUSE', errno: -4091, syscall: 'listen', address: '::', port: 5000

Tags: node.js

```
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1347:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 5000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Your port is already running, try killing task running in that port `pkill -9 node` will kill all node operations

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346211/how-to-kill-a-process-on-a-port-on-ubuntu

Comment: Another program has created a server on port 5000. Turn off the other server or choose a different port to run this server on.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problem but I have 3 fixes for this you can use any

- ### 1. a permanent and long way:

  - i. Install the kill-port node package as a dev dependency:

    ```
    npm install kill-port --save-dev
    ```
  - ii. Create a nodemon.json file in the root of your project containing:

    ```
    {
      "events": {
      "restart": "kill-port 5000",
      "crash": "kill-port 5000"
     },
    "delay": "1500"
    }
    ```
  - iii. Then, in your package.json file, have something like this:

    ```
    "scripts": {
    "start-dev": "nodemon app.js",
    }
    ```
  - iv. Then start your app in dev mode with:

    ```
     npm run start-dev
    ```
- ### 2. Manually kill from the system(easy fix):

  directly kill the port with the following command.

  ```
  fuser -n tcp -k 5000
  ```
- ### 3. Restarting the system:

  - restarting the project
  - restarting the computer

Answer (score 0):

For windows

```
netstat -ano | findstr : 5000
(output : TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 18264)
taskkill /PID 18264 /f
```

Mainly this error comes when we run our code on same port or port already busy, so we have to kill the process

For ubuntu

```
fuser -k 5000/tcp
```